# Create class like a folder and methods as files

Tags: python, class

I would like to know if is possible to break this class:

```
class Something:


   method1(self):
       pass


   method2(self):
       pass


   method3(self):
       pass


   __init__(self):
       self.x = 'x'
```

In files, like this:

```
/something
| something.py
| method1.py
| method2.py
| method3.py
```

I have obsessive compulsive disorder, and unfortunately this is the only way i could ever program in python...

Comment: First of all, OCD is not an excuse for bad programming practices. Seconds of all, this is doable. Third of all, you're mistaking class and a package.

Comment: Nothing built into the language, but it can be hacked together.

Comment: The `import` statement can be used to do this.

Comment: This would be going against the Python grain. The rule of thumb I use, and which I think is somewhat popular, is to have one class per file, and each method as small as possible. If your methods are really long to the point that you want to put them in their own files, they are probably *too* long. Refactor them and be happy.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not good enough, but a more complex example, certainly will show how impracticable this approach would be. Anyway, here we go.

An approach would be to have the **class** in one file and one file per **method**.

**something.py**

```
import show_value

class Something:

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def _show_(self):
        show_value.show(self.x)
```

**show_value.py**

```
def show(value):
    print value
```

There is many more ways, each one worse than another, to do it.

Anyway, try to imagine someone, sometime, trying to maintain your code. How painful it could be.